# Как запустить Gulp без подключения к интернету?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Здравствуйте. Опишите пожалуйста способ запуска Gulp без подключения к сети. Бывают моменты когда нахожусь в местах где сети нет, а gulp не запускается без подключения к интернету. Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность сделать это без интернета?

Спасибо.

Comment: у галпа нет привязки к интернету, если скачаны все нужные нпм пакеты, то все будет работать без интернета

Comment: у меня без интернета он не даёт ip localhost адресс.